# Oracle : Set column to heading length

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have the following result of a SELECT:

```
CXA|DSTRTG   |CB|
---|---------|--|
0A2|17-FEB-23|A2| 
0A2|17-FEB-23|A2| 
0A2|17-FEB-23|A2|
0A2|17-FEB-23|A2|
0A2|17-FEB-23|A2|
```

The column CB name is actually CBXF , and the length of data is CHAR(2) so the result is truncated based on this.
I want the result of the select to be like this

```
CXA|DSTRTG   |CBXF|
---|---------|----|
0A2|17-FEB-23|A2  |
0A2|17-FEB-23|A2  |
0A2|17-FEB-23|A2  |
0A2|17-FEB-23|A2  |
0A2|17-FEB-23|A2  |
```

I want to set it automatically (all the results fit the column length not the data length)

I tried increasing the parameters LINESIZE , LONG..., didn't work

Answer (score 2):

It is the `column` you must set.

Test case:

```
SQL> create table test (cxa varchar2(3), cbxf char(2));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values ('0A2', 'A2');

1 row created.
```

Current output (the last column name is missing some letters):

```
SQL> select * from test;

CXA CB
--- --
0A2 A2
```

Adjust it:

```
SQL> column cbxf format a4
```

Now it is OK:

```
SQL> select * from test;

CXA CBXF
--- ----
0A2 A2

SQL>
```

Comment: I don't have access to the tables to modify them , I just need to run some scripts on them to unload data.
That's why I am wondering if there is something general that can be changed to set the heading length to the data length

Comment: COLUMN SQL Plus command doesn't affect table description nor its contents. It just lets you format it so that everything is displayed as you want it. In this case, as column contents is 2 characters and column name length 4 characters (CBXF), setting it to A4 tells SQL Plus to *widen* it to 4 characters in length so that full column name is displayed. Read about that in SQL Plus documentation, it is well described. You might find some more interesting settings.